# zakat on mortgaged gold

Tags: zakat, gold

Do I owe Zakat on gold I put in bank and borrowed money against it in an emergency? I put it in the bank for 7 years. I pay it's monthly instalments and will inshallah own it again in 3 years time if I'm able to pay off all the instalments.

Answer (score 1):

Al-Nawawi (رحمه الله) said in al-Majmoo’ (5/318): If livestock or any other wealth that is subject to zakaah is being held in pledge, and one year has passed, then zakaah must be paid on it, because it is owned outright. End quote.

قال النووي رحمه الله في " المجموع " (5/318) : " لو رهن ماشية أو غيرها من أموال الزكاة ، وحال الحول وجبت فيها الزكاة ؛ لتمام الملك "
انتهى بتصرف

5 المجموع شرح المهذب
[image: المجموع شرح المهذب]

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (رحمه الله) was asked: Is zakaah due on property that is held in pledge?
He (رحمه الله) replied:
Zakaah is due on property that is held in pledge if it is wealth that is subject to zakaah, but the one who is holding it in pledge may pay zakaah on it if the owner agrees to that. An example of that is a man who puts a flock of sheep – as livestock are subject to zakaah – in pledge with a person, and zakaah must be paid on it, because the fact that it is in pledge does not mean that zakaah is waived. So he may pay zakaah on it, but with the permission of the one with whim he put it in pledge. End quote.
Majmoo’ Fataawa Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (18/34).

وقد سئل الشيخ ابن عثيمين رحمه الله : هل تجب الزكاة في المال المرهون ؟
فأجاب رحمه الله : " المال المرهون تجب الزكاة فيه إذا كان مالاً زكوياً ، لكن يخرجها الراهن منها إذا وافق المرتهن ، مثال ذلك : رجل رهن ماشية من الغنم ـ والماشية مال زكوي ـ رهنها عند إنسان ، فالزكاة فيها واجبة لابد منها ؛ لأن 
الرهن لا يسقط الزكاة ، ويخرج الزكاة منها ، لكن بإذن المرتهن " انتهى 
" مجموع فتاوى ابن عثيمين "  18 / 34

18 مجموع فتاوى ورسائل فضيلة الشيخ محمد بن صالح العثيمين
[image: مجموع فتاوى ورسائل فضيلة الشيخ محمد بن صالح العثيمين]